# Blitting from offscreen texture to screen (FB)

Tags: opengl

I am trying to do offscreen rendering and then blit to the screen ( default FB) , but all i see is a black window. I am just clearing offscreen texture to green and copy that to screen Framebuffer  .Here,s the code:

```
glGenTextures(1, &tex);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_BASE_LEVEL, 0);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL, 0);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, 640, 480, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);

glGenFramebuffers(1, &renderTexture);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, renderTexture);
glFramebufferTexture(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, tex, 0);

if(glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
{
    std::cout <<"\n Error in framebuffer";
}

GLint val = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER);

if(val != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
{
    std::cout <<"\n Error in framebuffer  : 2";
}

glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glClearColor(0.0f,1.0f,0.0f,0.0f);

glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, renderTexture);

glBlitFramebuffer(0, 0, 128, 128, 0, 0, 128, 128, GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT, GL_NEAREST);
```

Comment: Side note: there is no need to check the framebuffer status twice, which is what you're doing now. Only one is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the clear color to green after you did the clear so it was clearing it to the original clear color which unless you set it somewhere else would be black. You need to set the clear color before clearing the framebuffer. The code should be:

```
glClearColor(0.0f,1.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
```

See the description of glClearColor for reference: https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glClearColor.xhtml.